# Remove empty arrays in array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I have 2 arrays - `collections` and `settings`. IN `collections` array I need to remove empty arrays but the same index I need to remove from array settings so I write:

```
$.each(collections, function(index, collection) {
        if (collection.length == 0) { 
          collections.splice(index, 1); 
          settings.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
```

It works only for the first empty array but if there is more than 1 empty array I got error message:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')***

How to remove empty arrays from `collections` but at the same time to remove the same index from `settings` array?

Comment: Did you try using `filter()` method?

Comment: why not just `collections.filter( cl => cl.length !==0 )` ?

Comment: Yes, I try this code ollections = collections.filter(e => e.length); and works fine but how to remove index from settings array too

Comment: Loop through your array in reverse order using a standard for loop, or use `$.filter()`. The `$.each()` loop will loop over the original array length, and modifying your array by removing elements shrinks the array length, but doesn't change the number of iterations you do. As a result, you end up iterating over indexes that no longer exist in your array and you will also skip elements that shift into indexes that have already been visited by the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var collections = [
  [1],
  [],
  [],
  [2],
  []
];
var settings = [
  [5],
  [6],
  [7]
];

collections.forEach(function(collection, index) {
  if (collection.length === 0) {
    collections[index] = null;
    if (settings[index]) {
      settings[index] = null;
    }
  }
})

// then filter out the nulls
collections = collections.filter(function (v) { return v !== null });
settings = settings.filter(function (v) { return v !== null });

console.log('cols:', collections, 'setts:', settings); // cols:", [[1], [2]], "setts:", [[5], [8]]
```

fully working example is there: https://jsfiddle.net/5vfbdowL/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hynd5xs9/ please check, as you can see still empty arrays in array ...

Comment: just updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/5vfbdowL/1/. The better way is not to change the size inside the loop fn since we loose index rather mark elements and then filter out them safely

Answer (score 1):

Just do a truthy check before you access the length:

```
if (!collection || collections.length == 0) { ... }
```

(this will short-circuit if `collection` is falsy (`undefined` is falsy)  and thus no error will be thrown).

I'm not sure what ramifications the modification of the array within `$.each` is having, but you could also just do this:

```
let collectionsCopy = collections;

$.each(collectionsCopy, function(index, collection) {
    if (!collection || collection.length == 0) { 
        collections.splice(index, 1); 
        settings.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

(i.e. create an array whose only purpose is to loop over `collections` with - massively inefficient but this will work and is not dissimilar from your original approach.)

To make a more effective solution you could also just store the indices you want removed:

```
let indices = [];

$.each(collections, function(index, collection) {
    if (!collection || collection.length == 0) {
        indices.push(index);
    }
});

$.each(indices, function(_, index) {
    collections.splice(index, 1);
    settings.splice(index, 1);
});
```

If you'd like to use `filter`:

```
collections = collections.filter((collection, index) => {
    if (!collection || collection.length == 0) {
        settings.splice(index, 1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: $.each(collections, function(index, collection) {
        if (collection && collection.length == 0) { 
          collections.splice(index, 1); 
          settings.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }); this code does remove only 1st empty array and ignore all other empty arrays

Comment: @AleksPer I can am fairly certain that's not the case. If the element is `undefined` or an object with `length = 0` as a property (i.e. an empty array) then the `if` statement will be matched. You may be having issues if `$.each` uses the array as it is modifying itself. Perhaps use a duplicate and don't modify `collection` while you're looping through it? (I'm not exactly sure what problems this will cause).

Comment: here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hynd5xs9/

Comment: @AleksPer see my updated answer.

Comment: How I can use with .filter ?

Comment: @AleksPer added a `filter` solution which should work.

Comment: I think changes need in let indices = [];

$.each(collections, function(index, collection) {
    if (collection && collection.length == 0) {
        indices.push(index);
    }
});

$.each(indices, function(_, index) {
    collections.splice(index, 1);
    settings.splice(index, 1);
}); because we want position (values) from indices not index ...

Comment: Please test on jsfiddle all your solutions with this values var collections = [
  [1],
  [],
  [],
  [2],
  []
];
var settings = [
  [5],
  [6],
  [7],
  [8]
]; and you will see that is not correct

Comment: @AleksPer every time a `.splice()` occurs, the indexes will be off by one. This needs to be accounted for, eg: by pushing `indices.push(index-indices.length);`, will offset each index by the number of splices/shifts that will occur before it, allowing you to remove the correct element (although I think looping in reverse order makes things a bit clearer & avoids this particular casee)